# Keep bootstrap modal open after error on submit

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I use a bootstrap login modal. If there is a error after submit, the URL changes to soemething like `domain.com?error=102`

The error messaage will be displayed in the modal, that works fine. The problem is that the modal popup closes after the error.

How can i keep the modal open if the url changes to ?error=xxx ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.indexOf('?error=') != -1 || url.IndexOf('/?error=') != -1) {
$('#MyModal').modal('show');
}
</script>
```